# Creating views for Django ImageFields

Tags: django, image

I have the following django model with an ImageField:

```
class Pics(models.Model):
    def file_path(instance, filename):
        return '/'.join([instance.user.username, 'pics', filename])
    #...
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_path)
```

I know I can call ***pic.file.url*** to get the url to the image.  however, I'm wondering if Django also implements some functionality to automatically host that image?

The code I have currently works fine but it seems redundant:

```
#urls.py
    urlpatterns += patterns('views',
         url(r'media/(?P<name>\w{1,30})/pics/(?P<file>[^\\/:*?\"<>|]+)$', 'show_pic'),)
```

then my view is:

```
#app.views
import mimetypes
def show_pic(request, name, file):
     path = u'media/%s/graphics/%s' % (name, file)
     mime = mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0]
     image_data = open(path, 'rb').read()
     return HttpResponse(image_data, mimetype=mime)
```

Comment: Why do you want to serve media files through Django? This should be done by the webserver. So if you just put/upload the files to a path the webserver delivers there is no need for a view to show the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a view to serve the pictures you can directly point to `media/<name>/graphics/<file>` and let your webserver itself serve the images. Django is not well suited for serving static files, but your webserver on the other hand is designed to handle them efficiently.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that would be done.  From my understanding I would be using these images as html <image/> elements.  The source attribute has to point to a URL right?  How would I connect an html image element to my webserver (ie my computer's hardware?)?